# Question about the argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I was trying to do some roots of a complex number and I have $$\text{argument}= \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}\right)$$ How do you actually find the value in radians. From solutions I find $5\pi/12$, but in an exam, how are you supposed to find that? By approximations, like thinking how much is arctan of $1.73$?

Comment: arctan will only give you the result mod $\pi$ because $\arctan(\frac yx)=\arctan(\frac{-y}{-x})$ but in general the arguments of $(x,y)$ and $(-x,-y)$ differ by $\pm\pi$.

Comment: Well ok, I can rewrite it as   $\sqrt3+2$ , and arctan of $\sqrt3$ is 60 deg, but I still have a 2

Comment: Why can I take it as 60 deg, if I have that +2 aswell

Comment: I think your expression must be wrong. $\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}\right)$ is $\frac{5}{12}\pi$, not $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Oh, ok, but can you show me how you got to that?

Comment: It was probably wrong then

Comment: It would help me a lot

Comment: I got it with a calculator. In an exam you might be expected to recognise $\arctan(\sqrt 3)$ without a calculator, but not $\arctan(\sqrt 3+2)$.

Comment: Oh, I suppose you're right, thanks for telling me, I was wondering if it was possible by hand

Comment: thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta= \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}\right)$. Then,

$$\tan\theta= \frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}=\frac{1+\frac1{\sqrt3}}{1-1\cdot\frac1{\sqrt3}}
=\frac{\tan45+\tan30}{1-\tan45\cdot\tan30}=\tan(45+30)=\tan75$$